# Dar formato de fecha a un dato con JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

nuevamente haciendo uso de este excelente sitio para resolver dudas, miren me encuentro en un problema algo confuso. Hace un tiempo de hecho subi mi pregunta con un tema referente a este pero nadie me pudo auxiliar y investigue mas a detalle y logre la respuesta.
El tema era traer datos desde un php a JQuery y que JQuery rellenara los campos en otro php  que mostrara un formulario
los datos estaban en tipo JSON para su maleabilidad, hasta ahi no hay problema, y es que me encontre que tengo que traerme las fechas tambien en json para plasmarlas en el html pero al momento de traerlas las detecta como objetos y no como si estuviera trallendo los datos

es algo confuso pero mejor enseño el codigo

```
<php
if (isset($_POST['busca_info_us'])) {
 
      $id_user = $_POST['busca_info_us'];
      //echo $id_user;
       include_once "ConsultaADR.php";
       $cons = new ConsultaInfoADR();
       $datos_us = $cons->info_datos_us_2($id_user);
       header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
       echo json_encode($datos_us);
  
}
public function info_datos_us_2($id_us){
        include_once 'conexion.php';
        $BD = new ConexionSQL();
        $con = $BD->ObtenerConexionBD();
        $query = "SELECT [id_empleado_plant]
        ,emp.[no_empleado]
        ,ad.nombre_admin
        ,emp.id_admin
        ,emp.id_sub_admin
        ,emp.id_depto
        ,sub.nombre_sub_admin
        ,dep.nombre_depto
        ,puest_adr.id_puesto
        ,emp.[jefe_directo]
        ,pos.id_num_posision
        ,CASE WHEN(  emp.[tipo_nombramiento] = 1) THEN 'Base'
        WHEN(  emp.[tipo_nombramiento] = 2) THEN 'Confianza'
        WHEN(  emp.[tipo_nombramiento] = 3) THEN 'Eventual'
        WHEN(  emp.[tipo_nombramiento] = 3) THEN 'Honorarios'
        end as [tipo_nombramiento]
        ,puest_adr.nombre_puesto
        ,emp.[id_perfil]
        ,emp.[RFC] as rfc_comp
        ,emp.[CURP] as curp_comp
        ,emp.[rfc_corto]
        ,[nombre_s]
        ,[apellido_p]
        ,[apellido_m]
        ,emp.[correo_inst]
        ,emp.[correo_personal]
        ,emp.[numero_contacto_1]
        ,emp.[numero_contacto_2]
        ,emp.[ext_tel]
        ,emp.[estatus]
        ,emp.[user_alta]
        ,emp.[fecha_alta]
        ,emp.[user_mod]
        ,emp.[fecha_mod]
        ,emp.[user_baja]
        ,emp.[fecha_baja]
        ,emp.[id_proc]
        ,emp.[fec_ingreso]
         FROM [Control_Ingresos].[dbo].[Empleado_insumo] emp
        INNER JOIN Administracion ad ON emp.id_admin = ad.id_admin
      INNER JOIN SubAdmin sub ON emp.id_sub_admin = sub.id_sub_admin
      INNER JOIN Departamento dep ON emp.id_sub_admin = dep.id_depto
      INNER JOIN Posisiones pos ON emp.id_posision = pos.id_posision
      INNER JOIN Puesto_ADR puest_adr ON puest_adr.id_puesto = emp.id_puesto
      INNER JOIN Puesto_FUMP puest_fun ON puest_fun.id_puesto_fump = pos.id_puesto_fump
       WHERE  id_empleado_plant = $id_us and emp.estatus = 'A' 
";
        $respuesta = sqlsrv_query($con,$query);
        if($respuesta){
            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($respuesta, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $fila = $row;
            }
            if (isset($fila)) {
                return $fila;
                $BD->CerrarConexion($con);
            }else{
                return null;
                $BD->CerrarConexion($con);
            }
        }else{
            return print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true);
            $BD->CerrarConexion($con); 
        }  
    }
?>

<script> 
function Revisa_info_det_us(id_user_in) {
  // createCookie('users',id_user_in);
  var id_us = id_user_in;
  $("#Modal_detalle_usuario_insumo").modal();
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    datos: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    $('#datos_princip_us').html(data);
  })
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    busca_info_us: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    // var id_usuario = [];

    
    var rfc_c = [];
    var rfc = [];
    var curp = [];
    var nombre = [];
    var apellido_p = [];
    var apellido_m = [];
    var no_empleado = [];
    var id_puesto = [];
    var correo = [];
    var correo_p = [];
    var local = [];
    var area = [];
    var depa = [];
    var estatus = [];
    var num_tel1 = [];
    var num_tel2 = [];
    var ext = [];
    var fec_ingres = [];

    for (var i in data) {

      rfc.push(data.rfc_comp);
      rfc_c.push(data.rfc_corto);
      curp.push(data.curp_comp);
      nombre.push(data.nombre_s);
      apellido_p.push(data.apellido_p);
      apellido_m.push(data.apellido_m);
      no_empleado.push(data.no_empleado);
      id_puesto.push(data.id_puesto);
      correo.push(data.correo_inst);
      num_tel1.push(data.numero_contacto_1);
      num_tel2.push(data.numero_contacto_2);
      ext.push(data.ext_tel);
      correo_p.push(data.correo_personal);
      local.push(data.id_admin);
      area.push(data.id_sub_admin);
      depa.push(data.id_depto);
      fec_ingres.push(data.fec_ingreso);
      // jefe_directo.push(data.jefe_directo);
      estatus.push(data.estatus);


    }
    console.log(fec_ingres[0])
    
    if (rfc != null) {
      $("#RFC_COMP").val(rfc[0]);
      $("#RFC_CORTO").val(rfc_c[0]);
      $("#CURP2").val(curp[0]);
      $("#NOMBRE").val(nombre[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_P").val(apellido_p[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_M").val(apellido_m[0]);
      $("#NO_EMPLEADO").val(no_empleado[0]);
      $("#CORREO").val(correo[0]);
      $("#CORREO_P").val(correo_p[0]);
      $("#num_1").val(num_tel1[0]);
      $("#num_2").val(num_tel2[0]);
      $("#ext_tel").val(ext[0]);
      $("#fecha_ingreso").val(fec_ingres[0]);
      $("#id_admin option[value='" + local[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#id_sub_admin option[value='" + area[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_DEPA option[value='" + depa[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_PUESTO option[value='" + id_puesto[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#estatus option[value='" + estatus[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
     
    } else {
      alert('Los datos del usuario no estan disponibles.')
    }
  })

}


</script>
```

y solo tengo problemas con este dato en el formulario, todos responden bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega el código del método `info_datos_us_2()`, seguramente es ahí donde creas un objeto de fecha en lugar del formato adecuado.

Comment: ya lo agrego como respuesta

Comment: listo xd ya la edite la respuesta

Comment: puedes hacer un echo a "fec_ingres[0]" y "data.fec_ingreso" para saber que trae y saber como ayudarte.

Comment: hola amigo ya lo solucione, de hecho estaba por subir la respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen dia compañeros, ya solucione mi problema, lo que pasaba es que cuando se mandaban los datos por JSON los datos de string los manda bien salvo las fechas ya que estas las detecta como objetos, entonces lo que hice fue lo siguiente, segmentar ese objeto de la siguiente manera

```
function Revisa_info_det_us(id_user_in) {
  // createCookie('users',id_user_in);
  var id_us = id_user_in;
  $("#Modal_detalle_usuario_insumo").modal();
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    datos: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    $('#datos_princip_us').html(data);
  })
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    busca_info_us: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    // var id_usuario = [];

    
    var rfc_c = [];
    var rfc = [];
    var curp = [];
    var nombre = [];
    var apellido_p = [];
    var apellido_m = [];
    var no_empleado = [];
    var id_puesto = [];
    var correo = [];
    var correo_p = [];
    var local = [];
    var area = [];
    var depa = [];
    var estatus = [];
    var num_tel1 = [];
    var num_tel2 = [];
    var ext = [];
    var fec_ingres = [];

    for (var i in data) {

      rfc.push(data.rfc_comp);
      rfc_c.push(data.rfc_corto);
      curp.push(data.curp_comp);
      nombre.push(data.nombre_s);
      apellido_p.push(data.apellido_p);
      apellido_m.push(data.apellido_m);
      no_empleado.push(data.no_empleado);
      id_puesto.push(data.id_puesto);
      correo.push(data.correo_inst);
      num_tel1.push(data.numero_contacto_1);
      num_tel2.push(data.numero_contacto_2);
      ext.push(data.ext_tel);
      correo_p.push(data.correo_personal);
      local.push(data.id_admin);
      area.push(data.id_sub_admin);
      depa.push(data.id_depto);
      fec_ingres.push(data.fec_ingreso);
      // jefe_directo.push(data.jefe_directo);
      estatus.push(data.estatus);


    }
    var fec_ingresos = fec_ingres[0]['date'];
    
    if (rfc != null) {
      $("#RFC_COMP").val(rfc[0]);
      $("#RFC_CORTO").val(rfc_c[0]);
      $("#CURP2").val(curp[0]);
      $("#NOMBRE").val(nombre[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_P").val(apellido_p[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_M").val(apellido_m[0]);
      $("#NO_EMPLEADO").val(no_empleado[0]);
      $("#CORREO").val(correo[0]);
      $("#CORREO_P").val(correo_p[0]);
      $("#num_1").val(num_tel1[0]);
      $("#num_2").val(num_tel2[0]);
      $("#ext_tel").val(ext[0]);
      $("#fecha_ingreso").val(fec_ingresos);
      $("#id_admin option[value='" + local[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#id_sub_admin option[value='" + area[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_DEPA option[value='" + depa[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_PUESTO option[value='" + id_puesto[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#estatus option[value='" + estatus[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
     
    } else {
      alert('Los datos del usuario no estan disponibles.')
    }
  })

}
```

Esto hizo que el objeto se diviriera aun mas y me diera unicamente la fecha pero aun faltaba darle formato es ahi donde tuve que buscar como darle formato de la mejor manera o mas sencilla,

Lo que hice fue buscare una libreria de Js llamada moment y lo implemente para darle formato pero como estaba en formato JSON el formato de fecha era diferente a como lo detectaba moment

y quedo de la siguiente manera

```
function Revisa_info_det_us(id_user_in) {
  // createCookie('users',id_user_in);
  var id_us = id_user_in;
  $("#Modal_detalle_usuario_insumo").modal();
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    datos: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    $('#datos_princip_us').html(data);
  })
  $.post("php/consulta_dat.php", {
    busca_info_us: id_us
  }, function (data) {
    // var id_usuario = [];

    var id_user_in = [];
    var rfc_c = [];
    var rfc = [];
    var curp = [];
    var nombre = [];
    var apellido_p = [];
    var apellido_m = [];
    var no_empleado = [];
    var id_puesto = [];
    var correo = [];
    var correo_p = [];
    var local = [];
    var area = [];
    var depa = [];
    var estatus = [];
    var num_tel1 = [];
    var num_tel2 = [];
    var ext = [];
    var fec_ingres = [];
    var Escolaridad = [];
    var estat_escolar = [];
    var Carrera = [];
    var sex = [];
    var hijos = [];

    for (var i in data) {
      id_user_in.push(data.id_empleado_plant);
      rfc.push(data.rfc_comp);
      rfc_c.push(data.rfc_corto);
      curp.push(data.curp_comp);
      nombre.push(data.nombre_s);
      apellido_p.push(data.apellido_p);
      apellido_m.push(data.apellido_m);
      no_empleado.push(data.no_empleado);
      id_puesto.push(data.id_puesto);
      correo.push(data.correo_inst);
      num_tel1.push(data.numero_contacto_1);
      num_tel2.push(data.numero_contacto_2);
      ext.push(data.ext_tel);
      correo_p.push(data.correo_personal);
      local.push(data.id_admin);
      area.push(data.id_sub_admin);
      depa.push(data.id_depto);
      fec_ingres.push(data.fec_ingreso);
      // jefe_directo.push(data.jefe_directo);
      estatus.push(data.id_proc);
      Escolaridad.push(data.Escolaridad);
      estat_escolar.push(data.estatus_escolaridad);
      Carrera.push(data.Carrera);
      sex.push(data.Genero);
      hijos.push(data.Hijos);


    }
    var userDate = fec_ingres[0]['date'];
    var date_string = moment(userDate).format("MM/DD/YYYY");
    //console.log(date_string);

    if (rfc != null) {
      $("#RFC_COMP").val(rfc[0]);
      $("#RFC_CORTO").val(rfc_c[0]);
      $("#CURP2").val(curp[0]);
      $("#NOMBRE").val(nombre[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_P").val(apellido_p[0]);
      $("#APELLIDO_M").val(apellido_m[0]);
      $("#NO_EMPLEADO").val(no_empleado[0]);
      $("#CORREO").val(correo[0]);
      $("#CORREO_P").val(correo_p[0]);
      $("#num_1").val(num_tel1[0]);
      $("#num_2").val(num_tel2[0]);
      $("#ext_tel").val(ext[0]);
      $("#fecha_ingreso").val(date_string);
      $("#id_admin option[value='" + local[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#id_sub_admin option[value='" + area[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_DEPA option[value='" + depa[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#ID_PUESTO option[value='" + id_puesto[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#estatus option[value='" + estatus[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#sex option[value='" + sex[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#Hijos option[value='" + hijos[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#Escolaridad option[value='" + Escolaridad[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#estatus_esco option[value='" + estat_escolar[0] + "']").attr("selected", true);
      $("#carrera").val(Carrera[0]);
      $("#act_us_in_datos_basicos").attr("onclick", 'Actualiza_dat_basic(' + id_user_in[0] + ')');
    } else {
      alert('Los datos del usuario no estan disponibles.')
    }
  })

}
```

ahora ya con ese cambio y la libreria incluida queda el dato de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es todo el codigo anterior y aparte la libreria, con eso se soluciona este conflicto.